# Convergence or divergence of $\sum \frac{3^n + n^2}{2^n + n^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to conclude if the following series is convergent

$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{3^n+n^2}{2^n+n^3}.
$$

Can I get a hint? I tried to calculate $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ and to
see if the series is monotonically increasing and therefore divergent, but it seems like a difficult way.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: What is $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$ and what does that tell you?

Answer (score 3):

$$3^n+n^2\sim_03^n,\quad2^n+n^3\sim_\infty2^n,\enspace\text{hence}\quad \frac{3^n+n^2}{2^n+n^3}\sim_\infty\Bigr(\frac32\Bigl)^n,$$
which doesn't even tend to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the divergence test:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^n+n^2}{2^n+n^3}
 \stackrel{4 \times \text{L'Hôpital}}{=}
 \frac{\ln^4 3}{\ln^4 2} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n
$$

As the series tends to infinity, it behaves like a geometric series with $|r| = \frac{3}{2} > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac 1n<\frac 1n\left(\frac{n3^n+n^3}{2^n+n^3}\right)=\left(\frac{3^n+n^2}{2^n+n^3}\right)$$ Hence the series is divergent because the harmonic series $\sum \frac 1n$ diverges.